# gnuplot variable pointsize

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I try to plot a file with point of different size, as follow:

```
N = 3

symbol(N) = strcol(N) eq "3" ? 3 : ( strcol(N) eq "2" ? 2 : (strcol(N) eq "1" ? 1 : 0)  ) 

set xrange [0:6]
plot 'data.dat' using 2:1:(symbol(N)*1) with points pt 7 ps var
```

Actually this is correct if the third column is made by integers (i.e.: 1,2,5) but if the file is of the form:

```
#1st cl  2nd cl 3rd cl

 23.     0.       4.21
 34.     0.       1.2
 56.     0.       1.92
```

I can not be able to draw anything. Is it because I have to change something in the `symbol(N)` line ?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Why not just `plot 'data.dat' using 2:1:3 with points pt 7 ps var`? If you check for equality and don't provide data that are equal to "1", "2" or "3", there is nothing to display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are taking this complicated approach but I guess that this should be close to what you want to achieve:

Data set

```
#1st cl  2nd cl 3rd cl
 23.     0.       1.5
 34.     0.       2.5
 56.     0.       3.5
```

gnuplot command:

```
plot[ -1:7 ]  'data.dat' using 2:1:( column( 3 ) > 3 ? 3 : ( column( 3 ) < 2 ? 1 : 2 ) ) with points pt 7 ps var
```

Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not work with non-integer numbers because `symbol(N)` returns 0 when `N` is different from 1, 2, or 3:

```
gnuplot> symbol(N) = ( N==3 ? 3 : (N==2 ? 2 : (N==1 ? 1 : 0) ) ) 
gnuplot> print symbol(1.0), symbol(3.0), symbol(4.21), symbol(1.2)
1 3 0 0
```

These are some variations of this function that may help you:

```
symbol(N) = (floor(N) == N ? N : 0.5)     # return N if N is an integer; return 0.5 otherwise
symbol(N) = floor(N)                      # return largest integer not greater than N
symbol(N) = ceil(N)                       # return smallest integer not less than N
symbol(N) = N                             # just return N, doh'
```

Notice that I defined `symbol(N)` without `strcol(N)`, so you can call this function as:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 2:1:(symbol($3)) w p pt 7 ps var
```